# How to to take time as input OS X

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I am developing an application for OS-X. I want to take time as input from user. I have placed three text fields like below

[image]

But If I take input in this way How am I going to convert it into date&Time ? Because I want to compare this with system time.

How can I do that please advice ?

Answer (score 1):

Concate all `UITextField` data i.e

```
NSString * strTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@ %@",txtHours.text, txtMin.text, txtAMPM.text];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
NSDate *startD = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:strTime]; // this code is used for converting string into nsdate
```

Now, you can compare current system time with this above `NSDate`.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hey thanks for responcing. I converted your code into Swift and tried but it is returning me this date for above time "2000-01-01 07:59:00 +0000"

Comment: So you can compare it by your current time i.e NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

Comment: No, the returend date is wrong. its 2016 and its giving me year 2000